# How to make a ISO image from a Bootable DVD in windows?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, iso, dvd

I am using Windows 7. And I want to install ubuntu 12.04 to my new Notebook PC. It has no DVD-ROM so I wanna make *.iso file so I can install it fom a usb. I have the Ubuntu 12.04 bootable DVD.
How to make those files in the DVD a iso image?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [Imgburn.](http://www.filehippo.com/download_imgburn/)
2. Install it.
3. Now run the software.

   [image: Imgburn]
4. Select "Create image file from disc".

   [image: Create]
5. Select the "source". It's your DVD writer.

   [image: Source]
6. Select the "Destination".

   [image: Destination]
7. Click this icon.

   [image: Write]

Wait for your image file to be created. Finally, you get an iso file in the destination folder. Now, burn that to a USB and you are good to go.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an ISO from the DVD.  To do you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).  See image below.

[image]

Once created you can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable USB

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to just download the latest Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) than to create an ISO from that 12.04 DVD - [Download here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/)

However, if for whatever reason you want 12.04, you can get the ISO [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/)